# Google Calendar API Extended Properties not shown in event

Tags: php, google-calendar-api

I'm adding extended properties to my Google Calendar events via the Google API PHP library. I can see that it's stored in the event object after update. But it's not shown in the Calendar UI for an event. What could be the problem? Here is how I store it:

```
<?php 
$event = $service->events->get($calendar_id, $calendar_event_id);
$extendedProperties = new Google_Service_Calendar_EventExtendedProperties();
$extendedProperties->setShared(array('petsAllowed'=>'yes'));
$event->setExtendedProperties($extendedProperties);
?>
```